# redrawing code in C#

Tags: c#, drawing

i am creating a drawing programe which Suppose to take the parameters from the user
(Radius,height,width,....etc)
i have created a class with one paramter (radius)

```
public int faceoutline(int r)
    {
        Graphic = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        Graphic.DrawEllipse(myPen, 0, 0, r, r);
        return r;
    }
```

then i call it :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        faceoutline(int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
```

....and nothing happens
i copied the button code to a timer but it keep balnking
WHAT I AM DOING WRONG ?!

Comment: 1. Your rendering code should be in a place where it can be called when the control is redrawing itself, like in the override of OnPaint of the control. 2. Check the color and thickness of your pen. 3. 0,0 coordinates will render your ellipse on the top left corner of the control, offset them at least by the radius.

Comment: thx but i used the 0,0 coordinates just to experiment the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place the drawing code in the `Paint` event handler of the `PictureBox`, and use the `Graphics` provided in the event args. This way, your custom drawing code will be executed every time the control is redrawn.

If you don't do it this way, anything you draw will disappear the next time the control is redrawn. In your code, you call `Invalidate` right after you draw your ellipse, so the control is redrawn without the ellipse...

Comment: it's working just fine   thank you :) `private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
                int r = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, sp.X, sp.Y, r, r); 
        }`